# How to set C# individual Properties.Setting for different database? (Programmatically)

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

How to set C# individual Properties.Setting for different database?
I try but no matter how i try the Properties.Setting return value still the same value which set from other database.

My commRateA and commRateB value are show the last save value from which ever database save it from (my program are set for multiple database login).
 What I try to save the specify commRateA and commRateB value for different database, which I fail for doing it.

is there anyway to store the value which specify for each database? or it require to store at different folder?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So in plain terms, these settings are collecting values from a single db. Trick is this directly from C# and remove any db bindings at all. 
This would mean:
1. Read: C# reads values from different dbs and sets here
2. Write: C# collects values and writes to appropriate database.

It is not a good idea to have multiple origins within same app settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need to create database resource provider (IResourceProvider implementing), that allow you store your resources in db.

Comment: IResourceProvider implementing? Ok I will go to check out this section of guide advice.